# How to add module user control on page in DNN 6?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-6, dotnetnuke-imc

[image]

(This is how my module definition looks like.)

I am using DNN 6 and I have module with following user controls. Now when I add the module to be added on page it always show the View.ascx; so how can I show pagestarter.ascx?

My goal is I have page A and it should show VIew.ascx and I have page B that should show PageStarter.ascx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this you have three options.

1. Add a second module definition and add the second control to that as the item with no key. This will make it so everytime you add the module to a page both are added. You can then just delete the one you don't want.
2. Create the other as a separate module which will give a second item to add
3. Control the loading yourself within the main ascx that is registered by dynamically loading your desired control.

Comment: Thanks Mitchel Sellers, I have tried 1 and seems this will help. (accepted as answer.)